# extract only 0-9 numbers from string

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Need to extract all numeric characters i.e. (0-9) from a `varchar` column.
suppose we have data like `abc 123 456k`, then the output should be '123456', i.e the non numeric characters including spaces to be filtered out.
I am on Teradata version 15.10.

I have used `REGEXP_SUBSTR(ATRB_7_VAL, '[0-9]+')` and `REGEXP_REPLACE(ATRB_7_VAL,'[^0-9 ]*','')`, but both are not giving desired output.

```
create multiset volatile table abc
(
ATRB_7_VAL varchar(100)
)
on commit preserve rows;


insert into abc (
'abc 123 456 xyzabck'
);
insert into abc (
'123456 789k'
);
insert into abc (
'123456 789k 678-123*'
);

select ATRB_7_VAL
,REGEXP_SUBSTR(ATRB_7_VAL, '[0-9]+') as val1
,REGEXP_REPLACE(ATRB_7_VAL,'[^0-9 ]*','') as val2

from abc;
```

expected result

```
123456
123456789
123456789678123
```

Actual result with `REGEXP_SUBSTR(ATRB_7_VAL, '[0-9]+')`

```
val1
123
123456
123456
```

actual result with `REGEXP_REPLACE(ATRB_7_VAL,'[^0-9 ]*','')`

```
val2
123 456 xyzabck
123456 789k
123456 789k 678-123*
```

Comment: When you run `REGEXP_REPLACE('abc 123 456k', '[^0-9 ]*', '')` what is the output?

Comment: we get the numbers, but spaces are still there.
123456 789 678123
 123 456 
123456 789

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the pattern `[^0-9]*` with empty string:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('abc 123 456k', '[^0-9]*', '')
```

This should strip off any non digit character, *including* whitespace.